# paginate_links() outputs extra empty pages on custom loop

Tags: pagination, paginate-links

I have a custom loop:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$works = new WP_Query('category_name=work&posts_per_page=9&paged=' . $paged);
```

Pagination outputs 3 pages, on first there are 9 posts, which is also total number of posts, and on pages 2 and 3 there are no posts (there should be no pages if there are no posts on them, right?)

Here is my `paginate_links()`:

```
<?php elseif ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 && ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_search() || is_category() ) ) : // navigation links for home, archive, and search pages ?>

    <?php 
        global $wp_query;

    $big = 999999999;

    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'prev_text' => '',
        'next_text' => '',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ) );

    ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

On default loop everything is fine.

Comment: Try using [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) instead of WP_Query. That might solve issue. But I won't recommend so because of [these](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Caveats) factors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use your custom `WP_Query` to query posts, but then in pagination you use global `$wp_query` variable, which contains different query.

You should use your custom query variable `$works` in your pagination, or change global `$wp_query` variable before your pagination function call.

Since you use universal function to output pagination, second method will be better/easier. Do it like this:

```
global $wp_query;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$works = new WP_Query('category_name=work&posts_per_page=9&paged=' . $paged);

$original_query = $wp_query;  // store original query for later use
$wp_query = $works;  // overwrite it with your custom query

... your code

... your pagination code

$wp_query = $original_query;  // restore original query
```

Comment: actually now, some of my footer content is gone on page with the custom loop... it is conflicting with `do_shortcode()` function. any thoughts? thanks

Comment: Don't know what is in your footer and how is it done. Using `wp_reset_query` and `wp_reset_postdata` functions should help.

Comment: ah right :)... I am panicing a bit, can't think straight... thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Your code is magic! Thankfully I stumbled upon your answer as paginate_links in codec does not have enough info on custom queries and custom archive pages.

Answer (score 5):

Just use your custom `WP_Query/$works` object to access the data in the `paginate_links()` arguments as well.

```
paginate_links( array(
    'base'      => str_replace( 99999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 99999999 ) ) ),
    'format'    => '?paged=%#%',
    'prev_text' => '',
    'next_text' => '',
    'current'   => max( 1, $works->get( 'paged' ) ),
    'total'     => $works->max_num_pages
) );
```